# Why is FB not deduplicating my events even with same ID/Name? GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I send the same event to Facebooks Event Manager from FB pixel and Conversions API. I have made sure that the event name and eventID are the exact same, and that the server event is sent after the browser event.

[Screenshot from FB Events Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQWmr.png)

The events are not deduplicated in Event Manager. I have looked through the documentation but can´t find anything missing.

Answer (score 1):

Events Manager normally displays each event it receives (i.e. both Browser and Server events in this case), but they should be deduplicated in Ads Manager reporting.